# Padding in form text input gets stripped after a POST

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, post

Not sure if it's some coding flaw on my part, but the padding in the text inputs of a form seem to get stripped away when returning from a POST. This simplified example demonstrates it:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
    echo $_POST["name"]."<br />";
  }
?>    
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Input Padding</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      input[type=text]
        {margin: 20px; width: 200px; height: 25px; padding: 10px;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>     
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Strangely, it seems that it's the **ECHO** function that's causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Sofia

Comment: I am not able to understand your question. Do you mean the CSS padding is stripped when returning from a post?

Comment: What do you mean by "the padding in the text inputs"? You do know that HTML strips multiple space characters, right?

Comment: I think, this guy try to tell that, all the whitespaces on input text have gone after form post, why?

Comment: The **padding** from the styling gets stripped away or ignored after a form POST action; not the spaces/whitespaces. CrazySabbath's suggestion solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there can't be any white spaces/characters before html doctype declaration.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
    echo $_POST["name"]."<br/>;
  }
?>   
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Input Padding</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      input[type=text]
        {margin: 20px; width: 200px; height: 25px; padding: 10px;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>     
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you, from the bottom of my heart. I've been slicing and dicing my code for the past day trying to figure out what I did wrong, but to your keen and experienced eye, it took but a second. Amazing! Thank you.